# Unity3d Unet Adding script to GameObject results in Networkidentity disappear

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

All works well between the clients until i add this script to the GameObjects:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class TestScript : NetworkBehaviour {

}
```

I originally had code in the script to synchronize the rotation of the GameObject but during my testing I removed all code for testing.

I get the following error when the script is added:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   Pointer.On_Drag (.Gesture gesture) (at Assets/Script/Pointer.cs:247)
>   EasyTouch.RaiseEvent (EventName evnt, .Gesture gesture) (at Assets/EasyTouchBundle/EasyTouch/Plugins/EasyTouch.cs:1389)
>   EasyTouch.CreateGesture (Int32 touchIndex, EventName message, .Finger finger, SwipeDirection swipe, Single swipeLength, Vector2 swipeVector) (at Assets/EasyTouchBundle/EasyTouch/Plugins/EasyTouch.cs:818)

It is ONLY when i add the script that this happens!

Here is the related functions:

```
public void On_Drag(Gesture gesture) {
    if (!isLocalPlayer)
        return;


    if (singleTouch) {

        if (firstRun) {

            firstRun = false;

            linecast_GameObject_HashSet.Clear ();
            linecast_GameObject_HashSet = DoLinecast ();
            linecast_GameObject_List = new List<GameObject> (linecast_GameObject_HashSet);

            if (linecast_GameObject_List.Count > 0) {
                selected_GameObject = linecast_GameObject_List [0];
                if (selected_GameObject == null)
                    print ("NULL");

                childGameObject = GameObject.FindWithTag (linecast_GameObject_List [0].tag);
                childGameObject.transform.parent = myTransform.transform;
                print ("childGameObject: " + childGameObject.tag);
                // Assign Network Authority
                NetworkIdentity myNetID = childGameObject.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity> ();
>>      ERROR   print ("GO2: " + childGameObject.tag + " // myNetID: " + myNetID.netId);


                CmdAssignNetworkAuthority (myNetID.netId);


            }
        }

    }

    gesture.pickedObject.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (gesture.position.x, gesture.position.y, 1f));

}
```

The error is on this code line:

```
print ("GO2: " + childGameObject.tag + " // myNetID: " + myNetID.netId);
```

When do this it all works:

```
print ("GO2: " + childGameObject.tag);
```

Based on this i believe it is the Networkidentity that in one way or another is impacted.

Here is the Linecast function referred to in the code above:

```
HashSet<GameObject> DoLinecast () {
    GameObject linecast_GameObject;
    HashSet<GameObject> rayHashSet = new HashSet<GameObject> ();

    LayerMask theLayer;
    theLayer = (1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Fruit")); //set the layer to be clickable
    Vector2 clickedPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    //Get current worldspace position of mouse cursor
    RaycastHit2D[] hits = Physics2D.LinecastAll(clickedPos,clickedPos,theLayer);

    foreach (RaycastHit2D ray in hits) {
        linecast_GameObject = GameObject.Find(ray.collider.name);
        rayHashSet.Add (linecast_GameObject);
    }

    return rayHashSet;
}
```

Also, I use EasyTouch.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that `print ("GO2: " + childGameObject.tag)`; is working but `print("GO2: " + childGameObject.tag + myNetID: " + myNetID.netId);` is NOT working.

Either myNetID is null or netId is null which means that one or two of them are not initilized. Replace that line with the code below to find out which one it is:

```
if(myNetID==null){
Debug.Log("myNetID is null");
}

if(myNetID.netId==null){
Debug.Log("myNetID.netId is null");
}
```

This way you can figure out what to do next.

Comment: This is were the error is: "Debug.Log("myNetID is null"!! See above for the correct print statement. Still do not understand how, and why, myNetID is not initialized when adding the script?

Comment: I tested to move the script up in the GameObject hierarchy and the error disappeared. I do not understand that? I tested on an other GameObject and got the same error, which disappeared when i moved the script up in the hierarchy. I am puzzled.

Comment: myNetID is null which means that since your childGameObject.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity> () failed. Check your the childGameObject gameobject in your scene and make sure that it has NetworkIdentity component attached to it.

Comment: Also, if you are using server authority, you must use NetworkServer.Spawn() to spawn every gameobjects with NetworkIdentity attached to them and then NetworkInstanceId will be created. Not sure if this is your problem...

Comment: thanks for the help. All GameObjects have NetworkIdentity and are spawned correctly. Moving the script up in the Inspector hierarchy solve the problem.